# How to make a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, css

Using CSS style Sheet

I have the button  images, I want to add a button images in to my web page menus

For Example

```
Home           Contact 
 ->Aboutus        -> Location 

Home, Contact (menu)
Aboutus, Location(sub menu)

Button images name - button1.jpg
```

I want to add a my button image in the background of menus and sub menus

am new to web page designer

Need CSS Style Sheet Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure CSS Dropdown Menu:
 http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html

Horizontal Dropdown Menu: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/

CSS-Javascript Dropdown menu: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/chrome/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: CSS [background-image Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp)

Example:

```
.menu
{
  background-image:url('image.gif');
}
```

Then in your html add the above class:

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu">Home</li>
  <li class="menu">About Us</li>
  <li class="menu">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example was really easy to implement.  It doesn't focus on IE6 JS issues.  you'll need to use JS or JQuery to resolve those issues with IE not using `:hover` pseudoclass
[The No-Code Way to a Pure CSS Horizontal Drop-Down Menu with Expression Web](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd279540.aspx)